# PDFTron draw vertical box if layout is Horizontal

Tags: javascript, pdftron

I have below code which will draw rectangle when user press "Shift + Left Mouse Click"

```
 // Draw text box with alt + mouse left click
docViewer.on('click', (evt: any) => {
    if (evt.shiftKey) {
        // Get get window coordinates
        const windowCoords = getMouseLocation(evt);

        // Get current page number
        const displayMode = docViewer.getDisplayModeManager().getDisplayMode();
        const page = displayMode.getSelectedPages(windowCoords, windowCoords);
        const clickedPage = (page.first !== null) ? page.first : docViewer.getCurrentPage();

        // Get page coordinates
        const pageCoordinates = displayMode.windowToPage(windowCoords, clickedPage);

        // create rectangle
        const rectangleAnnot = new instanceAnnotations.RectangleAnnotation();
        rectangleAnnot.PageNumber = clickedPage + 1;
        rectangleAnnot.X = pageCoordinates.x;
        rectangleAnnot.Y = pageCoordinates.y - 14;
        rectangleAnnot.Width = 200;
        rectangleAnnot.Height = 14;
        rectangleAnnot.StrokeColor = new instanceAnnotations.Color(255, 0, 0, 1);
        rectangleAnnot.StrokeThickness = 2;
        rectangleAnnot.Author = annotManager.getCurrentUser();

        annotManager.addAnnotation(rectangleAnnot, false);
        annotManager.redrawAnnotation(rectangleAnnot);
    }
});
```

Now the issue is above code draw rectangle fine if PDF is vertical but if PDF is Horizontal then it draw Rectangle vertically. Please check below screenshot for reference.

[image]

As you can see on Page 1 it draws vertical box but on 2nd page its draws fine.
So how one can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for page rotation to ensure your rect is aligned with the page.
Here is a quick example of how you can achieve that using the [getCompleteRotation](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/CoreControls.DocumentViewer.html#getCompleteRotation__anchor) API, by setting width and height depending on the document rotation.

```
docViewer.on("click", (evt) => {
if (evt.shiftKey) {
  // Get get window coordinates
  const windowCoords = getMouseLocation(evt);

  // Get current page number
  const displayMode = docViewer.getDisplayModeManager().getDisplayMode();
  const page = displayMode.getSelectedPages(windowCoords, windowCoords);
  const clickedPage =
    page.first !== null ? page.first : docViewer.getCurrentPage();

  // Get page coordinates
  const pageCoordinates = displayMode.windowToPage(
    windowCoords,
    clickedPage
  );

  // create rectangle
  const rectangleAnnot = new Annotations.RectangleAnnotation();
  rectangleAnnot.PageNumber = clickedPage + 1;

  // Depending on doc orientation set Width and Height
  const rotation = docViewer.getCompleteRotation(clickedPage);

  const widthAndHeight = getWidthAndHeightBasedOnRotation(rotation);
  // You will have to adjust the X, Y  as well depending on rotation
  rectangleAnnot.X = pageCoordinates.x;
  rectangleAnnot.Y = pageCoordinates.y;

  rectangleAnnot.Width = widthAndHeight.width;
  rectangleAnnot.Height = widthAndHeight.height;
  rectangleAnnot.StrokeColor = new Annotations.Color(255, 0, 0, 1);
  rectangleAnnot.StrokeThickness = 2;
  rectangleAnnot.Author = annotManager.getCurrentUser();

  annotManager.addAnnotation(rectangleAnnot, false);
  annotManager.redrawAnnotation(rectangleAnnot);
}});

  const getWidthAndHeightBasedOnRotation = (rotation) => {
    switch (rotation) {
      case CoreControls.PageRotation["E_0"]:
        return {
          width: 200,
          height: 14,
        };
      case CoreControls.PageRotation["E_90"]:
        return {
          width: 14,
          height: 200,
        };
      case CoreControls.PageRotation["E_180"]:
        return {
          width: 200,
          height: 14,
        };
      case CoreControls.PageRotation["E_270"]:
        return {
          width: 14,
          height: 200,
        };
    }
  };
```

You can access the CoreControls object from the instance. Please note that you will also need to tweak your X,Y coordinates based on the rotation. [This is a good resource on PDF coordinates and viewer coordinates](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/coordinates/) to help you wrap your head around that part.